# Error using Cygwin: "collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault]"

Tags: c++, gcc, makefile, cygwin, mingw-w64

I'm trying to use cygwin to download [openslide](https://github.com/openslide/openslide-winbuild) (building natively on Windows) on a Windows 10 x64 system. I ran into an error earlier relating to `chk_fail` and set the line in the build file with `-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE` to 0 instead of the default (2). You can probably tell by now I don't really know what I'm doing. But I got a new error below relating to a memory error from what I've read. I tried deleting the whole package folder including the makefiles and object files, then clone from Github again and rebuild, but it didn't work. Can anyone give me pointers about what's happening here and how to fix it? It would be much appreciated.

```
Scanning dependencies of target ziptool
[ 90%] Building C object src/CMakeFiles/ziptool.dir/ziptool.c.obj
[ 90%] Linking C executable ziptool.exe
collect2: fatal error: ld terminated with signal 11 [Segmentation fault], core dumped
compilation terminated.
make[2]: *** [src/CMakeFiles/ziptool.dir/build.make:109: src/ziptool.exe] Error 1
make[2]: *** Deleting file 'src/ziptool.exe'
make[1]: *** [CMakeFiles/Makefile2:442: src/CMakeFiles/ziptool.dir/all] Error 2
make: *** [Makefile:161: all] Error 2
Failed: make $parallel (line 417)
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem. Firstly, don't even bother to build this package using Cygwin. It won't work because of dependency issues and there is no record for version control in the package README.

For anyone else who has this problem like I did, you can download the latest versions of the code here: https://github.com/openslide/openslide-winbuild/releases and pick the latest one.

I first pip installed openslide-python. Then I moved openslide-win64-20171122 (from Github) into anaconda3/site-packages (not necessary, but nice), and then from anaconda3/site-packages/openslide I opened lowlevel.py.

In lowlevel.py, you need to add the following lines:
(in the beginning after importing libraries)

```
os.environ['PATH'] = "path/to/openslide-win64-20171122/bin" + ";" + os.environ['PATH']
```

You can also change this line:

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    _lib = cdll.LoadLibrary('libopenslide-0.dll')
```

to this:

```
if platform.system() == 'Windows':
    _lib = cdll.LoadLibrary(util.find_library("libopenslide-0.dll"))
```

so that it searches for the libopenslide-0.dll file. Then don't forget to add `from ctypes import util` at the beginning.